# overflow of cummulative sum

Tags: c, overflow

Suppose I want to add 1+11+111....adding n times.
It is clear that from a certatin value of n, there may be an overflow of the cummulative sum.

Suppose I use the following very simple function to calcuate the sum above:

```
int calcSum(int num)
{
    int sum = 0, sequnt = 1, i;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        sum += sequnt;
        sequnt = (sequnt * 10) + 1;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

To that function I want to add a check for overflowing.

I have tried to get some help here [How to check if a number overflows an 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661481/how-to-check-if-a-number-overflows-an-int)

but I have to admit it made me confused, and I still find some difficulties with implementing it in my task.

Any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: `if(INT_MAX - sequnt >= sum)` it is safe to do `sum += sequnt;`

Comment: `INT_MAX` should be your friend

Comment: @WeatherVane That is not true for all events. Suppose for 16bit systems a call of calcSum(111111) will overflow to -19961 at function invocation. num will have a value of -19961 and because of integer promotion INT_MAX - -19961 will always be larger than sum.

Comment: @Kenneth 111111 is not a 16-bit value.

Comment: @WeatherVane It is a perfectly valid 16-bit long integer type.

Comment: @Kenneth the range of a 16-bit `int` is -32768 to 32767. Passing `111111` to a 16-bit `int` does not "overflow" to anything - it is *undefined behaviour*. Also there is no such thing as a 16-bit long integer type, which must be at least 32 bits.

Comment: @WeatherVane It is legal in C to call a function with a different integer type than specified by its signature. Integer litterals are interpreted at compile time to the smallest possible integer type which fits their value. Therefor an integer litteral of 11111 is interpreted as an int while 111111 is interpreted as a long. So calcSum(11111) is called with an int while calcSum(111111) is called with a long.   You will get a waring for the latter call but it is legal.

Comment: @Kenneth I don't see your point, which seems to be that something doesn't work if you pass an out of range value. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @WeatherVane Pardon the 16-bit long integer type. On that point you are correct. There is a long type for 16-bit systems which is 32-bits. But you can't just say garbage in, garbage out. Technically you are correct. My point is simply that you need to be aware of that garbage especially when passing variables to a function which have a different type. Or writing function calls manually using integer litterals. If you are not careful this will bite you at some point.

Comment: Well, there was a compiler warning. Don't issue code with compiler warnings.

Comment: @WeatherVane No. No, you cannot rely on that. If you call with an integer litteral there is a warning, like I said earlier. If you call with a long variable there isn't. Not even if you use -Wall.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `INT_MAX` from `limits.h`

```
int calcSum(int num)
{
    int sum = 0, sequnt = 1, i;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (INT_MAX - sequnt < sum) exit(1); // overflow
        sum += sequnt;
        if (INT_MAX/10 <= sequnt) exit(1); // overflow on the two next sentences.
        sequnt *= 10;
        sequnt++;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

The `exit(1)` is just to make the example short. You can add whatever error handling that you like.

Comment: I don't understand the need of checking against `INT_MAX/10` or `INT_MAX - 1`.  Can you explain the need to check for that and not for the signs of the two operands?  Do you know that if operands have same sign overflow is impossible?  What question are you trying to answer, because neither your code nor your explanation answers anything at all.

Comment: @LuisColorado Quote: "Do you know that if operands have same sign overflow is impossible?" What are you talking about? That statement is completely wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake on writing and tried to say _if two operands have different signs, then adding overflow is impossible_ instead..... See my answer, that has nothing about `INT_MAX/10` or `INT_MAX - 1`.

Comment: @LuisColorado I think you have misunderstood this completely. a) OP is not using any negative values so no need for discussing different signs. b) The multiplication may overflow as well so that has to be checked. All operation has be checked. Not just the add to `sum`

Comment: The code shows those errors also, but the question title is *only* about integer overflows _in cumulative_ sums.  It doesn't speak about multiplication anyway.  I agree with you in that way.

Comment: I cannot take the downvote off unless I edit the answer, so let me edit it to change `if (INT_MAX/10 < sequnt) exit(1);` to `if (INT_MAX/10 <= sequnt) exit(1);` to refund the two last tests into one (both can be done at once), and you'll get again the lost reputation.

Answer (score 3):

As either of the 2 additions or multiplication are roughly overflow candidates, call a safe [overflow checker](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/93699/29485) for each.  Use constants in `<limits.h>` to guide range checking.

```
#include <limits.h>
int is_undefined_add(int a, int b) {
  return (a < 0) ? (b < INT_MIN - a) : (b > INT_MAX - a);
}

int is_undefined_mult(int a, int b) {
  if (a > 0) {
    if (b > 0) {
      return a > INT_MAX / b;       // a positive, b positive
    }
    return b < INT_MIN / a;         // a positive, b not positive
  }
  if (b > 0) {
    return a < INT_MIN / b;         // a not positive, b positive
  }
  return a != 0 && b < INT_MAX / a; // a not positive, b not positive
}

int calcSum(int num) {
  int sum = 0, sequnt = 1, i;

  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    if (is_undefined_add(sum, sequnt) Handle_Overflow();
    sum += sequnt;

    if (is_undefined_mult(sequnt, 10) Handle_Overflow();
    sequnt *= 10;

    if (is_undefined_add(sequnt, 1) Handle_Overflow();
    sequnt++;
  }

  return sum;
}
```

---

`is_undefined_add()` and `is_undefined_mult()` are valid for all combinations of `int a, int b`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you are using two's complement signed integers, then you can check the following:  Two positive numbers added must give a positive result and two negative numbers added must give a negative result.  It's impossible in only one sum to get **two** overflows, so if you are adding positive numbers, an overflow will arrive when your result is negative for the first time.

Either case, if you want your code to be portable, then the recommendation is to do something similar to this:

```
#include <limits.h>
...
    if ((a > 0 && b > 0 && MAX_INT - a > b) ||
        (a < 0 && b < 0 && MIN_INT - a < b)) {
        /* OVERFLOW OF a + b WILL OCCUR */
        ...
    }
```

if signs of operands are different it is impossible for `a + b` to be greater than `a` or  `b` in absolute value, so it is impossible for an overflow to happen.

For `unsigned`s you have a similar approach (while you save half of the test, as operands can be only positive) but this time the first way is valid always (as standard says unsigned addition is considered a sum module `2^n` where `n` is the wordsize in bits) and in that case you can make the sum and later check if the result is less than any of the operands (if both are positive, sum must be larger than or equal than any of the operands):

```
unsigned a, b;

...
unsigned sum = a + b;
if (sum < a || sum < b) {
    /* OVERFLOW ON a + b HAS HAPPENED */
    ...
}
```

You have also to check for integer multiplication overflow.  If `a` and `b` are to be multiplied, then `a*b` can overflow.  But this time the problem goes further, as overflow can occur more than once, and you cannot do it *a posteriori*.  In that case you can have overflow with equal or different signs, as you are adding `a` times `b` (and `b` has the same sign as itself) if both signs are equal the product will be positive, and overflows will occur

```
if (MAX_INT/b < a) { /* overflow */ }
```

if signs are different, the product should be negative, and then

```
if (MIN_INT/b < a) { /* overflow */ }
```

if one of the numbers is 0, then no overflow occurs on multipliying, as the result is 0.

Comment: "if you are adding positive numbers, an overflow will arrive when your result is negative for the first time" It may be that way on some platforms but from a standard point of view it's wrong. When the overflow happens the behavior is undefined from a standard point of view and using the result is meaningless

Comment: Sorry, my apologies, I could assure I'd read somewhere.  Response edited.